# Do neutrons interact with electro-magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, interactions, neutrons

Does neutrons interact with electromagnetic fields? If yes, what kind of interactions would they undergo?

Comment: Look up neutron magnetic moment

Answer (score 4):

Although neutrons are electrically neutral, they are composed of charged quarks. There is therefore a net [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_magnetic_moment), resulting in its susceptibility to [magnetic forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Effects_of_an_external_magnetic_field_on_a_magnetic_moment). The neutron might also have a very small [electric dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment), which would make the neutron experience forces (so far, too small to measure) from electric fields.

Comment: The magnetic moment leads to magnetic neutron diffraction (for example from antiferromagnetic crystals). And there is the Aharanov-Bohm effect in neutron interference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @J.G.: neutrons interact electromagnetically via high energy photons, both real and virtual. For instance, elastic electron scattering off $^2$H and $^3\vec{\mathrm{He}}$ are sensitive the neutron electric and magnetic factors, which tell us about the distribution of charge and magnetic moment inside the neutron. Inelastic scattering is sensitive to the (charged) quark structure functions. Contrast this with photon scattering off of another neutral particle, the neutrino: it just doesn't happen.